# Wifi not connecting in Ubuntu 23.10

Tags: internet, ubuntu-gnome, connection, wifi-direct

There I am using Ubuntu 23.10 and when I am clicking on the wifi networks they are getting disappeared and come back instantly and I am not able to connect to my wifi network please help.

Please see the following video to clearly understand the problem:
[Google drive link](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1Hzu1jPdk1qr4J8ZlPfqug7sr-jqaC5Ec?usp=sharing)

Comment: Look at the network logs with the terminal command: `sudo journalctl -b 0 -u NetworkManager`. Read `man journalctl NetworkManager service`. Also do: `service NetworkManager status` and `service --status-all`.

Comment: Status is enabled and running. Please tell me what to do. I am not able to connect to my wifi.